# hide "Submitted by ADMIN on THU, xx/xx/xxxx - 00:00" in a view

Tags: views

I created a view listing a type of content.

This list shows the title of the content, publication information, images, link...
I would like to get ride of the publishing information but I don't find the wright parameteres.
Thank's to any of you who could help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't change that in view.

To perform this step, make sure you are logged on as an administrator, choose the content type you would like to edit by going to » Administration » Structure » Content types.

and under display settings tab, uncheck the display author and date information. Once you are done, save the content type

Comment: Thing is, author and date information don't appear in the fields displayed..

Comment: Found the answer! I had to edit my content type

Comment: You are hereHome » Administration » Structure » Content types  ans in the tab Display settings uncheck the box Display author and date information.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully you would have seen that.